# Access SQL that will display multiple maximum/minimum values and their corresponding case

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create an SQL query in Microsoft Access that will produce the maximum/minimum values for each of the fields below and return with their corresponding case attached

```
**Force Table**
case            Flxmax   Flxmin  Frxmax  Frxmin 
hs00p16010od    582.24   666.81  796.44  -451.15    
hs00p16015od    878.7    878.7   1096.3  -500.36    
hs00p16020od    1071.95  1071.9  1281.2  -743.05    
hs00p16025od    1186.65  1186.6  1397.8  -959.36
```

Desired Output

```
Flxmax   1186.65   hs00p16025od
Flxmin   666.81    hs00p16010od
Frxmax   1397.8    hs00p16025od
Frxmin   -959.36   hs00p16025od
```

Current Code (only maximizes 1 field and cannot choose 1 max for identical values)

```
SELECT case, [Flxmax]
FROM Force
WHERE [Flxmax] = (SELECT max([Flxmax]) FROM Force);
```

In addition, if there are multiple identical max/min values is there a way to pick just one.

Regarding the table, there are 40 fields in total including the ones shown here that require max/min values to be calculated. The number of records/cases is around 30,000.

I have 14 similar tables that I will need to run a similar query on (the case names, in the same order, being common among all of them). As you can imagine I want to keep the number of queries necessary to a minimum.

If there is a limitation with Access SQL, is it possible to do it using VBA?

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this one since it's a really oddball schema. As for your question `if there are multiple identical max/min values is there a way to pick just one` It's really up to you. What method would you use to pick just one? Perhaps the Max(case) or Min(case) wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a task for a spreadsheet.

Anyway:

```
Select "Flxmax" As FField, [case], [Flxmax] 
From (SELECT case, [Flxmax]
    FROM Force
    WHERE [Flxmax] = (SELECT Max([Flxmax]) FROM Force))
Union All
Select "Flxmin" As FField, [case], [Flxmin] 
From (SELECT case, [Flxmin]
    FROM Force
    WHERE [Flxmin] = (SELECT Min([Flxmin]) FROM Force))
Union All    
Select "Frxmax" As FField, [case], [Frxmax] 
From (SELECT case, [Frxmax]
    FROM Force
    WHERE [Frxmax] = (SELECT Max([Frxmax]) FROM Force))
Union All    
Select "Frxmin" As FField, [case], [Frxmin] 
From (SELECT case, [Frxmin]
    FROM Force
    WHERE [Frxmin] = (SELECT Min([Frxmin]) FROM Force))
```

and so on.

Comment: This is the only way to go with SQL. I was trying to think of a way around writing so many SQL statements union'd together, but OPs schema necessitates Unions to pull this off. A spreadsheet is one way to go, but I think a quick down and dirty VBA subroutine would do the trick too. Not sure which direction would be more painful.

Comment: Well, you asked for SQL, but I would certainly use VBA for this. For each min/max field, loop the recordset once (30000 isn't really that many records) finding the min/max value, locate the record and write that record to another table. Then the next field until no more fields. Much more fun than writing tedious SQL.

Comment: I assume the VBA code would run significantly faster if it just contained loops rather than a series of unions. If this is the case I would rather go the VBA route. I chose to avoid spreadsheets due to the volume of data lagging Excel (the main reason I switched over to a database like Access).
Can anyone link a VBA example for a similar problem that I can refer to because I'm not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside an SQL query, this test can be done on-the-fly with a user-defined function.

```
SELECT Case, Flxmax, Flxmin, Frxmax, Frxmin, 
    MAXPOSITIONz([Flxmax],[Flxmin],[Frxmax],[Frxmin]) As FieldPos,
    Choose([FieldPos],"Flxmax","Flxmin","Frxmax","Frxmin") As Choose1,
    Choose([FieldPos],[Flxmax],[Flxmin],[Frxmax],[Frxmin]) As Choose2
FROM MyTable
```

Result:

```
Case  Flxmax  Flxmin  Frxmax  Frxmin  FieldPos  Choose1  Choose2
aaaa  100000  100000  100000  100000         1   Flxmax   100000
bbbb  100000  100009  100008  100007         2   Flxmin   100009
cccc  100000  100001  100099  100099         3   Frxmax   100099
dddd  100001  100002  100003  100004         4   Frxmin   100004
```

The function:

```
'This function combines the features of Excel MAX() and Access Nz() to find Max, and allows Null or String'
Public Function MAXPOSITIONz(ParamArray ParameterData() As Variant) As Currency
    Dim Result As Currency: Result = 0
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim i as Long
    Dim ArrayLength as Long: ArrayLength = UBound(ParameterData) - LBound(ParameterData)
    Dim Position as Long: Position = 1
    
    If ArrayLength < 1 Then Return 1
    
    For i = 0 to ( UBound(ParameterData) - LBound(ParameterData) )
        If IsNumeric(Nz(ParameterData(i), "")) Then
            If CCur(ParameterData(i)) > Result Then
                Result = CCur(p)
                Position = i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    MAXPOSITIONz = Position
End Function
```

It is also possible to use a generic function that only returns the Max value:

```
            MAXz([Field01],[Field02], etc ...)     'Decimal Numbers
Int(        MAXz([Field01],[Field02], etc ...) )   'Whole numbers
CDate(      MAXz([Field01],[Field02], etc ...) )   'Date with time
CDate( Int( MAXz([Field01],[Field02], etc ...) ) ) 'Date without time
```

The generic function:

```
''This function combines the features of Excel MAX() and Access Nz() to find Max,
''and allows Null or String
Public Function MAXz(ParamArray ParameterData() As Variant) As Currency
    Dim Result As Currency: Result = 0
    Dim p As Variant
    
    For Each p In ParameterData
        If IsNumeric(Nz(p, "")) Then _
            If CCur(p) > Result Then _
                Result = CCur(p)
    Next p
    
    MAXz = Result
End Function
```

"As Currency" returns decimal numbers. If you don't want decimal, you can adjust the code specifically for Date or Long.