# VBA Access - How to return max/min from multiple fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need help with some VBA code in Microsoft Access that will produce the maximum/minimum values for each of the fields below and return with their corresponding case attached

**Force Table**

```
case            Flxmax   Flxmin  Frxmax  Frxmin 
hs00p16010od    582.24   666.81  796.44  -451.15    
hs00p16015od    878.7    878.7   1096.3  -500.36    
hs00p16020od    1071.95  1071.9  1281.2  -743.05    
hs00p16025od    1186.65  1186.6  1397.8  -959.36
```

**Desired Output**

```
Field     Force     Case  
Flxmax   1186.65   hs00p16025od
Flxmin   666.81    hs00p16010od
Frxmax   1397.8    hs00p16025od
Frxmin   -959.36   hs00p16025od
```

In addition, if there are identical max/min values in the table I need to pick just one in the results.

There are 30 additional fields to the ones shown above. I believe that I have to loop through each field till I reach the end and record the max/min row, but I'm unsure how to write this code. Any help would be great.

**Current Code**

```
Public Sub Max()

Dim sqlStatement As String
Dim rs1 As Object
Dim rs2 As Object
Dim fld As Field
Dim strName As String
Dim maximum As Long
Dim minimum As Long

 sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Force;"
 Set rs1 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sqlStatement)

 sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Results;"
 Set rs2 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sqlStatement)

 rs2.AddNew      'Add new record to result table

 'Field order to loop though: max, min, skip, max, min, skip...where skip implies a skipped field

 For Each fld In rs1.Fields
 With rs1
     maximum = DMax(fld, Force)
     'Write onto results tables
 End With

 Next fld

 rs2.Update  'Update results table

 Set rs1 = Nothing
 Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907636/access-sql-that-will-display-multiple-maximum-minimum-values-and-their-correspon

Comment: Well I took your advice to use VBA over SQL, but I am less experienced with VBA. I didn't receive any further response when I asked for some code I could refer to. 
Plus I couldn't find much information on looping fields so I thought it would be worth to ask the question.

Comment: It really should be quite simple. As I wrote: < For each min/max field, loop the recordset once (30000 isn't really that many records) finding the min/max value, locate the record and write that record to another table. Then the next field until no more fields >. What have you tried?

Comment: Well like I said I am pretty new to VBA and its syntax. I have added what I've written so far. I adapted it from a code I found online on regarding looping. The problem is that it goes through every single loop but I want a loop that has an order of max field1, min field 2, skip field 3...repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. What basically is missing is that every min/max field value must be added/updated separately to the target table.

**Revised Code**

```
Public Sub Max()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim newvalue As Long
    Dim newfield As String
    Dim newcase As String
    Dim sqlStatement As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Force;"
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStatement)

    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Results;"
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStatement)

    For Each fld In rs1.Fields
        rs1.MoveFirst

        newfield = fld.Name
        If newfield <> "case" Then
            newvalue = rs1(newfield).Value
            While Not rs1.EOF
                If Right(newfield, 3) = "min" Then
                    If newvalue > rs1(newfield).Value Then
                        newvalue = rs1(newfield).Value
                        newcase = rs1("Case").Value
                    End If
                ElseIf Right(newfield, 3) = "max" Then
                    If newvalue < rs1(newfield).Value Then
                        newvalue = rs1(newfield).Value
                        newcase = rs1("Case").Value
                    End If
                End If
                rs1.MoveNext
            Wend

            rs2.AddNew
                rs2!Field.Value = newfield
                rs2!Force.Value = newvalue
                rs2!Case.Value = newcase
            rs2.Update
        End If
    Next fld

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is air code and I don't have test data. You may need to add some error handling.

Comment: Works great. One issue I'm having is that its not returning the decimal values, only whole numbers. I changed newvalue to a Double type, and tried writing directly from tables [rs2!Force.Value = rs1("Flxmax").Value] to try eliminating the newvalue variable altogether--no decimals.

Comment: Of course. Missed that. Do Dim newvalue As Currency or Double and make sure the field in table Results are of such a datatype as well.